# private [this] w/ Case Class Parameters

Tags: scala

Given:

```
$scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_101).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object F { def f(a: A) = a.hidden }
case class F(private [this] val hidden: Int)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:12: error: private[this] not allowed for case class parameters
       case class F(private [this] val hidden: Int)
                                       ^
```

Why is `private [this]` not allowed for case class parameters?

Comment: Probably because case classes are emulating functional "records", which have all "public fields". That just pushes the question back, but a better question to ask is "Why do functional records only have public members?".

Comment: Carcigenicate, but it's possible to have plain private field in case class, only private[this] doesn't seem to work. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that the companion object generated for the case class needs to access all of its fields, for example for pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

Allowing `private[this]` could break pattern-matching on `F`, because `F.unapply` wouldn't be able to access the value it needs to make the proper comparison. The compiler could probably be made to find a way to handle object private members, since `unapply` compiles down to statics anyway, but it would make things awfully complicated.

[SI-1422](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1422) discusses a bug that arose when using `private[this]` in case classes, and it was simply removed from the language without much public discussion. It seems fixing the behavior would have been too complicated to cover a use-case that well, really *shouldn't* be a use-case of case classes.

Here is the [commit](https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/3cf0e5a010ca8d3bd1828bbc096f587a01ba604f) that introduces the compiler error.

Comment: `case class C(private val c: Int)` uses accessor `c$1` in pattern match, not `C.unapply`. It could do the same with `private[this]`. Maybe something else would break.